# Inserting a TableCell into the correct section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I am trying to add a tableCell into the appropriate section in my TableView. I have a list of Clients that are indexed as such:

```
 var clients = Client.loadAllClients()     //Returns client array
 var contacts = [String: [Client]]()
 var letters: [String] = []
```

When I do my indexing, the contacts dictionary returns:

```
 {A: [Client("Andrew")]}
```

Letters array returns:

```
 [A]
```

Which I then use to index the whole list of clients and put them in to the proper sections with section headers. This all works well. However, I am confused on how to add a new client into this indexed table, so that the client's name will lineup with the proper section header.

I am using the *prepare* function to pass the newly created Client object back to the TableViewController and then I am appending it to the client array. I know the array has the information, but I can not get the cell to display in the table. Through some research I have come up with this:

```
    @IBAction func addNewClient(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let newClient = addNewClientData()
    let firstLetter = charToString(c: [getFirstLetter(s: newClient.lName)]).capitalized
    if !letters.contains(firstLetter) {
        letters.append(firstLetter)
        contacts[firstLetter] = [Client]()
        letters.sort()
    }
    let sectionIndex = Int(letters.index(of: firstLetter)!)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: contacts[firstLetter]!.count - 1, section: sectionIndex)], with: .automatic)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
    contacts[firstLetter]!.append(newClient)

}
```

This function runs when the "save" button is pressed on a different view. I have the object, I am confused on how to insert it into the correct index and section in the table. I receive an invalid number of sections when I run this. I am using xCode 8.0 and Swift 3.0. If I need to give any additional information, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: • Get the first character of the client • Get the index of the character in `letters` (that's the section) • If the index does not exist, insert the character in `letters` and add a key-value pair `contacts["<character>"] = [Client]()` in `contacts` • Append the client in the client array of the correspondent character (that's the row). • Update `contacts` by assigning the array back.

Comment: Can you explain the last to bullet points more please? So far I this:       `index = letters.index(of: firstLetter)!
 let clientIndex = contacts[lName[lName.startIndex]]?.count`                             The index is for the "section" and the clientIndex is for "row"

Comment: The IndexPath you're passing in `insertRows` looks really strange to me.  If you have 10 contacts in the array and you're inserting an 11th contact, do you want to insert at row 10, section 11?  What is appearing in rows 0-10 in section 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question through asking a different question. The problem with my dictionary was the fact that it was a dictionary. While dictionaries will work for indexing and tables, arrays are more optimized for Swift and Xcode. The solution was to make a data structure that works as an array. Below is the link to the solution for the data structure:

[Filtering an Array inside a Dictionary - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43053141/filtering-an-array-inside-a-dictionary-swift)

Now to insert a new client:

```
let newClient = Client(lName: cLast)
    let firstLetter = newClient.getFirstLetter(s: cLast).capitalized
    for contact in contacts {
        if firstLetter == contact.letter {
            contact.add(client: newClient)
        } else {
            let tempContact = Contact(letter: firstLetter, clients: [newClient])
            contacts.append(tempContact)
            break
        }
    }
    indexClients()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```