# Filtering an Array inside a Dictionary - Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to search through a indexed dictionary to return a specific client based on the client's last name. Below are the data structures I am using. Each client object has a name property which is a String.

```
var clients = Client.loadAllClients()     //Returns client array
var contacts = [String: [Client]]()      //Indexed clients in a dictionary 
var letters: [String] = [] 

var filteredClient = [Client]()
var shouldShowSearchResults = false
var searchController : UISearchController!
```

When I do my indexing, the contacts dictionary returns:

```
{A: [Client("Andrew")]}
```

Letters array returns:

```
[A]
```

I am using the UISearchController to display the filtered array of clients.

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    // how to filter the dictionary 
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

However, I have no idea how to filter the dictionary to return the correct list of clients. I have tried to use

```
contacts.filter(isIncluded: ((key: String, value: [Client])) throws -> Bool((key: String, value: [Client])) throws -> Bool)
```

But I was very confused about the implementation. I am using Xcode 8.0 and Swift 3.0.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything. Thank you in advance. The full code can be found at my [Github](https://github.com/brandenk514/iKennel/blob/master/iKennel/ClientTableViewController.swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are using a **dictionary** as data source **array**.

My suggestion is to use a custom struct as model

```
struct Contact {
   let letter : String
   var clients : [Client]

   init(letter: String, clients : [Client] = [Client]()) {
      self.letter = letter
      self.clients = clients
   } 

   mutating func add(client : Client) {
        clients.append(client)
   }
}
```

Then create your data source array

```
var contacts = [Contact]()
```

and the letter array as computed property

```
var letters : [String] = {
   return contacts.map{ $0.letter }
}
```

It's easy to sort the array by letter

```
contacts.sort{ $0.letter < $1.letter }
```

---

Now you can search / filter this way (`text` is the text to be searched for)

```
 filteredClient.removeAll()
 for contact in contacts {
     let filteredContent = contact.clients.filter {$0.name.range(of: text, options: [.anchored, .caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil }
     if !filteredContent.isEmpty {
         filteredClient.append(filteredContent)
     }
 }
```

You can even keep the sections (letters) if you declare `filteredClient` also as `[Contact]` and create temporary `Contact` instances with the filtered items.

Of course you need to change all table view data source / delegate methods to conform to the `Contact` array, but it's worth it. An array as data source is more efficient than a dictionary.

Comment: This approach is a good one but I think there is an issue because of Struct, when I try call add method and try to append new client instance, clients array doesn't get this instance. I check memory addresses before and after appending an element and they are different.
So do you know what's the issue here or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: structs are value types. In many cases instances are copied when being assigned to a new variable.

Comment: Yes I am aware of struct being value type and I think that's why in my case I can't use struct as datasource for sectioned table view. I have to use dictionary.
What are your thoughts?

Comment: Swift Dictionary is value type, too. The memory address is irrelevant, the contents are crucial. If you really need reference semantics use a `class`.